# Generating combinations without recursion

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

Given a list of strings and a length, give all combinations of that list with the given length. The problem is: **your code must not be recursive.** Yes, it can be done. I have done it myself, when I had no clue what this "recursion" was.

**Input:** A list of strings of an undefined length, and an integer defining the length of the combination. The strings will be at least one character long, and will only contain letters or numbers. The way of input will be specified by you, the programmer.

**Output:** A list of possible combinations as strings, not necessarily distinct (although you can make it that way, if you like). You do not have to sort the list.

**Test Cases:**
As said before, the method of input will be specified by you.
`[a,b] 3 -> Nothing`
`[1,0,0] 2 -> 10 10 00`, or `00 10` if distinct.
`[abc,bcd,cde] 2 -> abcbcd abccde bcdcde`

If you even manage to do this, I will commend you. As always, shortest code wins. Good luck.

Comment: what does "without recursion" mean in this context? can you use a while loop? for loop? context would be helpful here...

Comment: If I look at your third test case, it seems that you care about the order. Is `cdeabc` a valid combination?

Comment: Yes it is. Why not?

Comment: @beary605 Because your test case says it is not.

Comment: Are we permitted to assume that none of the input strings are empty or contain newlines?

Comment: Yep. Hehe, how would you input newlines?

Comment: @rhymingorange Ehehe, recursion is when you call a function in itself.

Comment: @beary605 I understand what recursion is. it's just that you can do the equivalent of recursion using a while loop with very little difficulty. Just trying to tease out the "spirit" of the problem.

Comment: @rhymingorange It depends on the recursive algorithm, but yeah, that's true.

Comment: To howards question: Shall we ignore the order of elements? So for example 3: abc-bcd = bcd-abc?

Comment: Yep, whatever goes. As long as you have them all in there.

Comment: Not all languages have to offer looping constructs other than explicit recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### GolfScript (<strike>44 42</strike> 32 chars)

```
n%){\,=}+[[]]@1/{`{1$+}+%}%;\,n*
```

This takes input on stdin as a list of newline-separated strings followed by a line containing the desired subset size. It assumes that none of the input strings is empty. It takes some inspiration from Howard's solution, and can be shortened by two chars if using his input format:

```
~{\,=}+[[]]@1/{`{1$+}+%}%;\,n*
```

Output is a newline separated list of concatenations.

E.g.

```
$ golfscript.rb subcombo.gs <<END
> a
> b
> c
> 2
> END
ab
ac
bc
```

Note: this uses a horribly inefficient algorithm. A much nicer implementation in terms of performance is (<strike>62</strike> 61 chars)

```
n%)~\:S;2\?({2S,?<}{:s.~)&.s+.s^@4*/|}/{:x;S{;x.2/:x;1&},}%n*
```

which uses [Gosper's hack](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/whats-your-favorite-bit-wise-technique/67087#67087).

Comment: How do you even stumble across such obscure programming nuggets?

Comment: @Gareth, I was taught this one by [Arthur Norman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norcroft_C_compiler). It's part of a collection of interesting titbits called [HAKMEM](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/hakmem.html).

Comment: Answer to you! You are pretty much the only answerer, other than the other GolfScript, that didn't use a built-in combo generator.

Answer (score 4):

#### GolfScript, <strike>33</strike> <strike>35</strike> 34 characters

```
~[[]]@{\{.[2$]+.,4$={puts}*}%\}%];
```

Assumes that the input is list of strings and number in GolfScript compatible format (on STDIN). Example:

```
> ["abc" "bcd" "cde"] 2
abcbcd
bcdcde
abccde
```

You can also test this version [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydbImFiIiAiY2QiICJlZiIgImdoIiAiaWoiXSAzJwoKfltbXV1Ae1x7LlsyJF0rLiw0JD17LnB1dHN9Kn0lXH0lXTs=).

*Edit:* The first version was broken.

Comment: `puts`? Seriously?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maybe I don't understand you correctly, but why not? Btw I just noticed that we can save a char and get rid of the dot.

Comment: It's so long that I think its only purpose is debugging. You can save two more chars by ditching `puts` and just filtering the list to ones of the right length: `~[[]]@{\{.[2$]+}%\}%;{,1$=},\;n*`

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 21

```
""<>##&@@@Subsets@##&
```

Usage:

```
""<>##&@@@Subsets@##&[{"a", "b", "c", "d"}, {3}]
```

> {"abc", "abd", "acd", "bcd"}

Comment: My goodness, that's really compact.

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <strike>34 30</strike> 24 characters

```
StringJoin@@@Subsets@@#&
```

where i is input consisting of a list of the strings and the length of combinations. 
For example,

```
k = {{"abc", "bcd", "cde"},{2}};
StringJoin@@@Subsets@@#&[k]

(* out *)
{"abcbcd", "abccde", "bcdcde"}
```

---

Additional examples:

```
d = {"a", "b", "cd", "e", "fgh"}
m = {d, {2}}
n = {d, {3}}
p = {d, {4}}

StringJoin@@@Subsets@@#&[m]
StringJoin@@@Subsets@@#&[n]
StringJoin@@@Subsets@@#&[p]
(* out *)
{"ab", "acd", "ae", "afgh", "bcd", "be", "bfgh", "cde", "cdfgh", "efgh"}
{"abcd", "abe", "abfgh", "acde", "acdfgh", "aefgh", "bcde", "bcdfgh", "befgh", "cdefgh"}
{"abcde", "abcdfgh", "abefgh", "acdefgh", "bcdefgh"}
```

Comment: Ha! Mma beating golfscript and J ... :D

Answer (score 1):

### J, <strike>50</strike> <strike>48</strike> <strike>46</strike> <strike>44</strike> <strike>43</strike> <strike>41</strike> 35 characters

```
;"1(>@{:{."1(i.@!@#A.])@}:)".1!:1[1
```

Takes input from the keyboard. I've changed the input format from previous answers. Strings should come first, single-quoted, and separated by semi-colons, followed by the integer.

```
   ;"1(>@{:{."1(i.@!@#A.])@}:)".1!:1[1
'hello';'mr';'wibble';2
hellomr
hellowibble
mrhello
mrwibble
wibblehello
wibblemr
```

Entering a number larger than the largest possible combination just gives the largest possible combination:

```
   ;"1(>@{:{."1(i.@!@#A.])@}:)".1!:1[1
hello mr wibble 8
hellomrwibble
hellowibblemr
mrhellowibble
mrwibblehello
wibblehellomr
wibblemrhello
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala 52

Not a challenge - know your API:

```
def c(l:Seq[_],n:Int)=l combinations n mkString "\n"
```

invocation sample:

```
scala> c(Seq("foo", "bar", "foobar"), 2)
res199: String = 
List(foo, bar)
List(foo, foobar)
List(bar, foobar)
```

Now beary605 observes that he didn't thought about library methods *combinations*, so I come up with this one, which doesn't use  *combinations*, but maybe he now will come up with a permutation prohibition.

#### Scala 63 (without literal combinations method):

```
def c(l:Seq[_],n:Int)=l.permutations.map(_.take(2).toSet).toSet
```

Comment: Hehe, I should have added "no using built-in combo functions", but oh well.

Comment: @beary605: Posted an alternative solution. Now you prohibit permutation, :) then map, then println?

Comment: Hahaha. Very clever. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 208 characters

**No imports, two method calls**,
so it should be pretty guaranteed that there are no *implisit* recursive calls neither.

```
class S{public static void main(String[]a){int n=a.length-1,k=Integer.parseInt(a[0]),i=0,j;while(++i<1<<n)if(Integer.bitCount(i)==k){String s="";for(j=0;j<n;)if((i&1<<j++)!=0)s+=a[j];System.out.println(s);}}}
```

Slightly more readable:

```
class S{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        int n=a.length-1,k=Integer.parseInt(a[0]),i=0,j;
        while(++i<1<<n)
            if(Integer.bitCount(i)==k){
                String s="";
                for(j=0;j<n;)
                    if((i&1<<j++)!=0)
                        s+=a[j];
                System.out.println(s);
            }
    }
}
```

Takes input from command line arguments. First arg is the length and the rest is the strings. Outputs each combination on a separate line:

```
$ java S 3 A B C D
ABC
ABD
ACD
BCD
```