# Shortest power set implementation

Tags: code-golf, array, combinatorics

### Problem definition

Print out the powerset of a given set. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3] => [[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Each element is to be printed on a separate line, so the above example would be printed as:

```
[]
[1]
[2]
...
[1, 2, 3]
```

### Example code (in D, python example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/whats-a-good-way-to-combinate-through-a-set)):

```
import std.stdio;

string[][] powerset(string[] set) {
    if (set.length == 1) {
        return [set, []];
    }

    string[][] ret;
    foreach (item; powerset(set[1 .. $])) {
        ret ~= set[0]~item;
        ret ~= item;
    }

    return ret;
}

void main(string[] argv) {
    foreach (set; powerset(argv[1 .. $]))
        writeln(set);
}
```

### Input

Elements will be passed as arguments. For example, the example provided above would be passed to a program called `powerset` as:

```
powerset 1 2 3
```

Arguments will be alphanumeric.

### Rules

1. No libraries besides io
2. Output does not have to be ordered
3. Powerset does not have to be stored, only printed
4. Elements in the set must be delimited (e.g. `1,2,3`, `[1,2,3]` and `['1','2','3']` are acceptable, but `123` is not

   - Trailing delimiters are fine (e.g. `1,2,3, == 1,2,3`)
5. *Best* is determined based on number of bytes

The best solution will be decided no less than 10 days after the first submission.

Comment: Closely related to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6380

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51468/21348

Comment: If only this challenge was updated to allow the defaults, like returning and functions. Python would be 54 bytes: `lambda L:reduce(lambda r,x:r+[s+[x]for s in r],L,[[]])`.

Comment: I'm not agree in only print... Why not allow to have the data, the variable too.. Than why print in column and not in row?

Answer (score 16):

## Mathematica 16

**Code**

`Subsets` is native to Mathematica.

```
Column@Subsets@s
```

The code (without column) can be [verified on WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Subsets%5B%7B1,2,3%7D%5D). (I had to use brackets instead of `@`; they mean the same thing.

**Usage**

```
s={1,2,3}
Column@Subsets@s
```

[image: output]

---

This method (55 chars) uses the approach suggested by @w0lf.

```
s #&/@Tuples[{0,1},Length@s]/.{0:>Sequence[]}//Column
```

**Breakdown**

Generate the tuples, composed of `0` and `1`'s of length `Length[s]`

```
Tuples[{0, 1}, Length@s]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1,
>      1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}

Multiply the original list (vector) by each tuple:

```
s # & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, Length@s]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 3}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 3}, {1,
>      2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}

Delete the `0`'s. `%` is shorthand for "the preceding output".

%/. {0 :> Sequence[]}

> {{}, {3}, {2}, {2, 3}, {1}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}

Display in column:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @tjameson I had serious doubts about whether I should post it, but I thought some people might find it interesting to know it is built-in.

Comment: I find it interesting :)

Comment: Can you leave off the `s` and put the input at the end of the line?

Comment: 15 bytes: `Subsets/*Column` makes an anonymous function that takes a list and returns the display in columns.

Answer (score 10):

### C, <strike>118</strike> 115

Whilst can save approx 20 chars with simpler formatting, still not going to win in code golf terms either way.

```
x,i,f;
main(int a,char**s){
    for(;x<1<<a;x+=2,puts("[]"+f))
        for(i=f=0;++i<a;)x&1<<i?f=!!printf("%c%s","[,"[f],s[i]):0;
}
```

Testing:

```
/a.out 1 2 3
[]
[1]
[2]
[1,2]
[3]
[1,3]
[2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: Nice. Some tips: K&R style (`main(a,s)char**s;{...}`), `f|=x&1<<i&&printf` is shorter than `?:`.

Comment: Just figured out what's behind `x+=2` (and where did `s[0]` go). Really nice trick.

Comment: Refusing to golf your answer because it's "still not going to win in code golf terms either way." makes the answer not a serious contender for the winning criteria of the challenge.

Answer (score 7):

#### GolfScript, <strike>22</strike> 18 characters

```
~[[]]{{+}+1$%+}@/`
```

Another attempt in GolfScript with a completely different algorithm. Input format is the same as with w0lf's answer. ([online test](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydbMSAyIDNdJwoKfltbXV17eyt9KzEkJSt9QC9g&run=true))

Comment: +1 Great solution! Mine is refactored for readability :-P

Answer (score 5):

### GolfScript (43 chars)

This may seem quite long, but it's the first solution to follow the spec: input is from command-line arguments, and output is newline-delimited.

```
"#{ARGV.join('
')}"n/[[]]\1/{`{1$+.p}+%}%p;
```

E.g.

```
$ golfscript.rb powset.gs 1 2 3
["1"]
["2"]
["2" "1"]
["3"]
["3" "2"]
["3" "1"]
["3" "2" "1"]
[]
```

Comment: Quotes aren't necessary, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @tjameson, the quotes come from using the shortest possible way to print. The fact that those values are strings rather than integers comes from the inability of GolfScript to access command-line arguments directly: it has to rely on the interpreter doing an eval in Ruby and putting the result in a string.

Answer (score 4):

### awk (82)

```
{for(;i<2^NF;i++){for(j=0;j<NF;j++)if(and(i,(2^j)))printf "%s ",$(j+1);print ""}}
```

assume saved in file powerset.awk, usage

```
$ echo 1 2 3 | awk -f powerset.awk

1
2
1 2
3
1 3
2 3
1 2 3
```

**ps** if your awk doesn't have and() function, replace it with `int(i/(2^j))%2` but adds two to the count.

Comment: `(2^j)` -> `2^j` saves you 2 bytes; the `.awk` file also works without a trailing `\n`, so you could shave off another byte.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 98

Sadly, a good chunk is spent on output formatting.

```
for(n in a=eval(prompt(i=p=[[]])))
    for(j=i+1;j;)
        p[++i]=p[--j].concat(a[n]);
alert('[]'+p.join('\n'))
```

#### Input

Takes a JavaScript array. (e.g. [1,2,3])

#### Output

```
[]
1
1,2
2
2,3
1,2,3
1,3
3
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python <s>70</s> 67 bytes

```
def p(a,*v):
 i=0;print v
 for n in a:i+=1;p(a[i:],n,*v)
p(input())
```

Input is taken in the same manner as for [ugoren's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9045/shortest-power-set-implementation/9060#9060). Sample I/O:

```
$ echo [1,2,3] | powerset.py
()
(1,)
(2, 1)
(3, 2, 1)
(3, 1)
(2,)
(3, 2)
(3,)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxDoAgEATAnldsCUoh2GF4iaEgUeI1x8Wgia9HnXrkaUdl3/u2F4jOdrhNUKA4LXISN9wKpZ5gECMHGqNbvrZSSJb/rEQTy9W0Mb2vzsJbzOkF)

Comment: You can save some with `def p(a,*v)` and then `p(a[i:],n,*v)`. Output becomes somewhat uglier, but still OK.

Comment: Very clever, thanks for the tip.

Comment: For the down-voter (over 7 years later), this is obviously Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

### J, 19 chars

```
   (<@#~#:@i.@(2&^)@#)

   (<@#~#:@i.@(2&^)@#) 1 2 3
┌┬─┬─┬───┬─┬───┬───┬─────┐
││3│2│2 3│1│1 3│1 2│1 2 3│
└┴─┴─┴───┴─┴───┴───┴─────┘
```

The ascii boxing in the output is called `boxing` and provides heterogen collection (for different length of arrays here).

Answer (score 2):

### Golfscript 48

```ruby
~:x,:§2\?,{[2base.,§\-[0]*\+x\]zip{~{}{;}if}%p}%
```

This program uses the binary representations of numbers from 0 to length(input) to generate powerset items.

#### Input

The input format is the Golfscript array format (example: `[1 2 3]`)

#### Output

The output is a collection of arrays separated by newlines, representing the power set. Example:

```
[]
[3]
[2]
[2 3]
[1]
[1 3]
[1 2]
[1 2 3]
```

#### Online Test

The program can be tested online [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydbMSAyIDNdJwoKfjp4LDrCpzJcPyx7WzJiYXNlLizCp1wtWzBdKlwreFxdemlwe357fXs7fWlmfSVwfSU%3D&run=true).

Comment: Awesome, but could you delimit with newlines?

Comment: @tjameson I managed to output delimited by newlines while keeping the same character count. Please see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Python (<strike>74</strike> 70 chars)

```
def p(a,v):
 if a:i,*a=a;p(a,v);p(a,v+[i])
 else:print v
p(input(),[])
```

for input as `1,2,3` or `[1,2,3]`, output is:

```
[]
[3]
[2]
[2, 3]
[1]
[1, 3]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `[a[0]]` = `a[:1]`

Comment: with input `1,2,3` `a[:1]` not works. tuple+list not allowed. Exist better solution

Comment: Isn't `i,*a=a` Python 3? It doesn't work on my 2.7.1.

Comment: Nor on 2.7.2. That might explain why I've never seen that trick before... most code golf servers run 2.7.x.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell (96)

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment
main=getArgs>>=mapM print.filterM(\_->[False ..])
```

If importing `Control.Monad` isn't allowed, this becomes **100** characters:

```
import System.Environment
main=getArgs>>=mapM print.p
p z=case z of{[]->[[]];x:y->p y++map(x:)(p y)}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 39

```
$*.map{p *$*.combination($.)
$.+=1}
p$*
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mathematica 53**

```
Column@Fold[#~Join~Table[x~Join~{#2},{x,#}]&,{{}},#]&
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## C# 164

Man this is hard in C#!

```
void P<T>(T[]c){foreach(var d in c.Aggregate<T,IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>>(new[]{new T[0]},(a,b)=>a.Concat(a.Select(x=>x.Concat(new[]{b})))))Console.WriteLine(d);}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Scala, 81**

```
def p[A](x:Seq[A]){x.foldLeft(Seq(Seq[A]()))((a,b)=>a++a.map(b+:_)).map(println)}
```

Answer (score 2):

### APL (26)

Reads input from keyboard because there's no `argv` equivalent.

```
↑⍕¨(/∘T)¨↓⍉(M/2)⊤⍳2*M←⍴T←⎕
```

Usage:

```
      ↑⍕¨(/∘T)¨↓⍉(M/2)⊤⍳2*M←⍴T←⎕
⎕:
      1 2 3
3    
2    
2 3  
1    
1 3  
1 2  
1 2 3
```

Explanation:

- `T←⎕`: read input, store in `T`
- `M←⍴T`: store length of `T` in `M`
- `(M/2)⊤⍳2*M`: generate the bit patterns for `1` upto `2^M` using `M` bits.
- `↓⍉`: split the matrix so that each bit pattern is separate
- `(/∘T)¨`: for each bit pattern, select those sub-items from `T`.
- `↑⍕¨`: for output, get the string representation of each element (so that it will fill using blanks and not zeroes), and format as a matrix (so that each element is on its own line).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (*ES6*) 76

Partially copied from this one: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51502/21348

Using a bitmap, so it's limited to no more than 32 elements.

Run the snippet in Firefox to test.

```js
f=l=>{ 
  for(i=0;i<1<<l.length;i++)
    console.log(l.filter(v=>[i&m,m+=m][0],m=1))
}  

// TEST

// Redefine console to have output inside the page
console = { log: (...p) => O.innerHTML += p.join(' ') + '\n' }

test=()=>{
  var set = I.value.match(/[^ ,]+/g)
  O.innerHTML='';
  f(set);
}

test()
```

```css
#I,#O { border: 1px solid #aaa; width: 400px; padding:2px}
```

```html
Insert values, space or comma separated:<br>
<input id=I value='1 2 3'> <button onclick="test()">-></button>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## K, 14 bytes

```
{x@&:'!(#x)#2}
```

Generate all 0/1 vectors as long as the input, gather the indices of 1s and use those to select elements from the input vector. In practice:

```
  {x@&:'!(#x)#2} 1 2 3
(!0
 ,3
 ,2
 2 3
 ,1
 1 3
 1 2
 1 2 3)
```

This is a bit liberal with the output requirements, but I think it's legal. The most questionable part is that the empty set will be represented in a type dependent form; `!0` is how K denotes an empty numeric vector:

```
  0#1 2 3      / integers
!0
  0#`a `b `c   / symbols
0#`
  0#"foobar"   / characters
""
```

### Explanation

The `(#x)#2` builds a vector of `2` as long as the input:

```
  {(#x)#2}1 2 3
2 2 2
  {(#x)#2}`k `d `b `"+"
2 2 2 2
```

When monadic `!` is applied to a vector, it is "odometer":

```
  !2 2 2
(0 0 0
 0 0 1
 0 1 0
 0 1 1
 1 0 0
 1 0 1
 1 1 0
 1 1 1)
```

Then we use "where" (`&`) on each (`'`) vector to gather its indices. The colon is necessary to disambiguate between the monadic and dyadic form of `&`:

```
  &0 0 1 0 1 1
2 4 5

  {&:'!(#x)#2} 1 2 3
(!0
 ,2
 ,1
 1 2
 ,0
 0 2
 0 1
 0 1 2)
```

If we just wanted combination vectors, we'd be done, but we need to use these as indices into the original set. Fortunately, K's indexing operator `@` can accept a complex structure of indices and will produce a result with the same shape:

```
  {x@&:'!(#x)#2} `a `c `e
(0#`
 ,`e
 ,`c
 `c `e
 ,`a
 `a `e
 `a `c
 `a `c `e)
```

Elegant, no?

Comment: This is no longer valid, as "odometer" in oK now generates a flipped matrix. It can be corrected at the cost of a single byte: `{x@&:'+!(#x)#2}`. Unrelated: a shorter equivalent of `(#x)#2` is `2|~x`.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 64 bytes

Using comma-separated input:

```
P=[[]]
for i in input():P+=[s+[i]for s in P]
for s in P:print s
```

### Pyth, 4 bytes (using builtin) or 14 bytes (without)

As noted by @Jakube in the comments, Pyth is too recent for this question. Still here's a solution using Pyth's builtin powerset operator:

```
jbyQ
```

And here's one without it:

```
jbu+Gm+d]HGQ]Y
```

You can try both solutions [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jbyQ&input=1,+2,+3&debug=0) and [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jbu%2BGm%2Bd%5DHGQ%5DY&input=1,+2,+3&debug=0). Here's an explanation of the second solution:

```
jb       # "\n".join(
 u       #  reduce(
  +G     #   lambda G,H: G+
   m     #    map(
    +d]H #     lambda d: d+[H],
    G    #     G),
  Q      #   input()
  ]Y     #   [[]]))
```

Answer (score 2):

### brainfuck, 94 bytes

```
+[[<+>>+<-]++[>-<------]>-[>]<<[>>+>]>,]++++++++++[[[<]<]+[-[>[.>]]<[<]>+[>]>]<<
.[<<[<]>-]++>]
```

Formatted:

```
+
[
  [<+> >+<-]
  ++[>-<------]>-[>]
  <<[>>+>]
  >,
]
++++++++++
[
  [[<]<]
  +
  print
  [
    -[>[.>]]
    <[<]
    >+[>]
    >
  ]
  <<.
  increment
  [
    <<[<]
    >-
  ]
  ++>
]
```

Expects input of the form `9,10,11` without a trailing newline, and outputs subsets in the same format, sometimes with a trailing comma. The first line printed will always be empty, signifying the empty set.

[Try it online.](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=K1tbPCs-Pis8LV0rK1s-LTwtLS0tLS1dPi1bPl08PFs-Pis-XT4sXSsrKysrKysrKytbW1s8XTxdK1stWz5bLj5dXTxbPF0-K1s-XT5dPDwuWzw8WzxdPi1dKys-XQ&input=MSwyMyw0LDU)

The basic idea is to place a bit next to each element, then repeatedly increment the binary number while printing the corresponding subset before each increment. (A bit indicates whether an element is in the subset.) A sentinel bit to the left of the array is used to terminate the program. This version actually creates an exponential number of sentinels to save some bytes; a more efficient 99-byte solution that only uses one sentinel can be found in the revision history.

Each bit is encoded as one plus its value; i.e., it can be either `1` or `2`. The tape is laid out with the bit before each element and a single zero cell between adjacent elements. The comma is included on the tape for non-final elements, so we can conveniently just print elements without doing any extra work to handle delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŒPŒṘ€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390UsDRSQ93znjUtCby////hjpGOsYA)

`ŒṘ€Y` are string formatting.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
⍪,⊃∘.,/⎕,¨⊂⊂⍬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQZcjzra0/4/6l2l86ir@VHHDD0dfaCczqEVj7qaQKh3zX@giv9pXIYKRgrGAA)

Output:

```apl
 1 2 3 
 1 2   
 1 3   
 1     
 2 3   
 2     
 3
```

There's a blank line at the end to represent the empty set.

Explanation:

`⎕` evaluated input

`⎕,¨⊂⊂⍬` append an empty numeric list after each element

`∘.,` Cartesian product

`/` reduction (foldr)

`⊃` disclose (necessary after reduction in APL)

At this point the result is an n-dimensional 2-by-...-by-2 array, where n is the length of the input.

`,` flatten into a vector

`⍪` turn the vector into an upright 2<sup>n</sup>-by-1 matrix, so each subset is on a separate line

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```hs
import System.Environment
main=getArgs>>=mapM(print.concat).mapM(\a->[[a],[]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRCG4srgkNVfPNa8ssyg/Lzc1r4QrNzEzzzY9tcSxKL3Yzs42N7HAV6OgKDOvRC85Py85sURTDywUk6hrFx2dGKsTHRur@f//f5P/xv@N/hsCAA)

Comment: The I/O requirements are horrible, however people are interpreting them quite loosely. If you change to taking input via *stdin* you could save 15 bytes, [see this](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM882M68ktSgxuUSlNC8nMy@1WC83sUCjOCO/XC85Py85sUQTJOCrEZOoaxcdnRirEx0bq6lXnl@UUvz/v4mCsYKRgiEA "Haskell – Try It Online").

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
def f(s,p=[[]]):
 for e in s:
  for u in p:p=p+[u+[e]]
 print p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HccrDsAgDABQv1NUQsCMORJO0tSNZhho@Iidvvs89@SeV6tB9cwMbIaXhEhk4wbcOmQoFcabf@ubREnicDnMRBtIL3WCKBvcffAHWX0A)

Comment: Note that the spec (unnecessarily) requires each element to be output on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes

```js
a=>alert(a.reduce((a,x)=>[...a,...a.map(y=>[...y,x])],[[]]).join`
`)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

a=>alert(a.reduce((a,x)=>[...a,...a.map(y=>[...y,x])],[[]]).join`
`)

f([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Why the `alert`?

Comment: @Shaggy The challenge explicitly asks to _print_ each element on a separate line -- which would probably frowned upon with our current standards. Most answers seem to stick to this rule.

Comment: Ah, fair enough; I interpreted "print" as "output".

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, <s>5</s> 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

<s>Sadly, Japt's built-in for getting the powerset of an array doesn't include the empty array or this would be 1 byte.</s> It does now!

```
à
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=4A&input=WzEsIDIsIDNd) (the empty line at the end is the empty set or you can [run it with the `-Q` flag](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVE&code=4A&input=WzEsIDIsIDNd) instead to visualise the sub-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
⊇ᵘẉᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FX@8OtMx7u6ny4dcL//9GGOkY6xrEA)

```
  ẉ     Write on its own line
 ᵘ ᵐ    every unique
⊇       subset of the input.
```

Comment: Since this doesn't seem to have been a downvote-every-golflang incident, I'm interested in knowing what's wrong with my answer in particular...

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 31 bytes

Accidentally cut my previous byte-count in half answering another prompt...

```sh
for i;a=({$i,}\ $^a)
<<<${(F)a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxPy2/SCHTOtFWo1olU6c2RkElLlGTy8bGRqVaw00zsfZ/QVFmXomCuq2trbomF1eagqGCEYRUMFYwAbISFZIUkv8DAA)

Delimiter is one or more spaces, we abuse trailing delimiters extensively here.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 1 byte

```
y
```

Since Pyth has implicit `Q` (input variable) at the end of programs, this is basically just power set of the input. I don't think this violates any rules (although 'No libraries besides io' is a bit vague)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v/L//2hDHQUjHQXjWAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](//php.net), 102 bytes

```php
<?php
function p($a){
$b=[[]];foreach($a as $c)foreach($b as $d)$b[]=array_merge([$c],$d);return $b;
}
```

## [Go](//golang.org), 118 bytes

```go
package m
func p(a ...int)[][]int{b:=[][]int{{}}
for _,c:=range a{for _,d:=range b{b=append(b,append(d,c))}}
return b}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ʠ¶j
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDQSVBMCVDMiVCNmomZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xJTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDMmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
ʠ¶j  # Implicit input
ʠ    # Take the powerset
 ¶j  # Join on newlines
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 1 byte

```
S
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FguDlxQnJRdDeQuWRxvqGOkYx0K4AA)

`S` finds a subset of a list.

By default, Nekomata prints all possible results separated by newlines.

Answer (score 0):

### Python, <strike>93</strike> 87 chars

Python makes formatting simple, because the required input/output matches its native format.
Only supports items which are Python literals (e.g. `1,2,'hello'`, not `1,2,hello`).
Reads standard input, not parameters.

```
f=lambda x:x and f(x[1:])+[x[:1]+a for a in f(x[1:])]or[()]
for l in f(input()):print l
```

Comment: `print f(input())` shorter

Comment: @AMK, the requirement is for each element to be printed in one line. But `list` can indeed be removed (if also replacinf `[[]]` with `[()]`.

Comment: `print'\n'.join(f(input()))` saves two characters

Comment: @beary605, doesn't work, `f()` contains tuples, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ruby Array method combination (from 1.9 ) [50 chars]

```
0.upto(ARGV.size){|a|ARGV.combination(a){|v| p v}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 74 bytes

```
def f(x):
    for i in reduce(lambda s,e:s+[i+[e] for i in s],x,[[]]):print i
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell 89 chars

```
import System.Environment
main=getArgs>>=mapM print.p
p[]=[[]]
p(x:y)=(map(x:)$p y)++p y
```

Getting parameters is long :/

Comment: one more char can be shaved off with `map(x:)(p y)++p y` and yet two more chars above that with `[(x:),id]<*>p y`. Apparently [`<*>` is in the Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-) now. (`filterM` isn't).

Answer (score 0):

### R, 63

```
y=lapply(seq(v),function(x)cat(paste(combn(v,x,s=F)),sep="\n"))
```

Here, `v` represents a vector.

**Usage**:

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3)
y=lapply(seq(v),function(x)cat(paste(combn(v,x,s=F)),sep="\n"))
1
2
3
c(1, 2)
c(1, 3)
c(2, 3)
c(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 51

More cheating:

```
Column@ReplaceList[Plus@@HoldForm/@#,x___+___->{x}]&
```

Use with `@{1,2,3}`.

Comment: Your code should take the set as input, not just hardcode it. Also, since this is code golf, you should include the byte count of the code (and probably remove the unnecessary spaces).

Comment: Since this contest is long over, the post was more for the idea, but I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab (46)

```
v=input(''),for i=1:numel(v),nchoosek(v,i),end
```

---

- the input must be of the form [% % % ..] where % is a number

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, 22 bytes

```
say words.combinations
```

The built in `combinations` method will give all N-combinations of a list, ie. the powerset. Arguments provided via STDIN

```
% echo 1 2 3 | ./powerset.p6
(() (1) (2) (3) (1 2) (1 3) (2 3) (1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, 5 bytes

```
à i[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AChczo2P//ow11jHSMY7m4dIMA)

Comment: [Beat you to it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154668/58974)! :p Also, note the (unnecessary) requirement of each element being on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 117 bytes

```
(labels((p(l &aux(x(car l)))(if x`(,@#1=(p(cdr l)),@(mapcar(lambda(m)(cons x m))#1#))'(()))))(mapcar'print(p(read))))
```

Input is a list of element, in output the sets are printed as lists (empty list is equal to NIL)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3RCsIwFEN/5ULBJbCX6rOwT/GunVBoZ2kV@vfzTsxjcpKEnHo9DmRdt9yBiiwX/QwMBG2SSSI9ZTwwL87fLQ/xZ88LilZjrFrWqChEeO1dhhTSeUdOAE/9wam2tL9toW0aT99uvVzlxi8)

If the answer can be a function that returns the result, then:

### Common Lisp, 90 bytes

```
(defun p(l &aux(x(car l)))(if x`(,@#1=(p(cdr l)),@(mapcar(lambda(m)(cons x m))#1#))'(())))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvBCoMwEEXRX3kQ0DfgJu1a8FM6JhUCSRy0Qv4@td0e7g05ndY743u7KowZg16NjUEPZBFh2tBenBbnZxpD/PO0sKjdDbOWNSqLMOz1REMRcd6JjOS9S6cdqX5Aw0iPB54//AI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 90 bytes

```
def p(l)=(fmap((+)$(l[:1]),p(l[1:])))+p(l[1:])if l else[[]]
fmap(print,p(input().split()))
```

I *think* I had something one byte shorter but I lost it after experimenting more.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/PyU1TaFAI0fTViMtN7FAQ0NbU0UjJ9rKMFZTBygcbWgVq6mpqQ1jZqYp5Cik5hSnRkfHxnKBdRQUZeaVANVm5hWUlmho6hUX5GQCaU3N//8NFYwUjBVMFEwB)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 78 bytes

```php
for(;$i<1<<$argc;$i+=2)for(print$c=_;$argc>$c+=1;)$i&1<<$c&&print"$argv[$c],";
```

prints a comma after each element and an underscore before each subset. Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/248d66ccc87874bfff7b6459a6794706c2676221).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
æ»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJDu///jzbUMdIxjgUA)

Output is space-delimited (i.e. `1 2 3`). If you want it as actual lists (i.e. `[1, 2, 3]`), add `€¸` before the `»`:

```
æ€¸»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJHTWsO7Ti0@///aEMdIx3jWAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
æ     # Take the powerset of the (implicit) input-list
   »  # Join the lists by newlines (and each inner list by spaces)
      # (and output the result implicitly)

 €¸   # Wrap each inner list into a list
      # (i.e. [[1],[1,2]] → [[[1]],[[1,2]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
S=lambda A:A and[u+[A[0]]for u in S(A[1:])]+S(A[1:])or[[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9g2JzE3KSVRwdHKUSExLyW6VDvaMdogNjYtv0ihVCEzTyFYwzHa0CpWM1Ybxsovio6Ojf1fUJSZVwKUjjbUMYrV/A8A)

Answer (score 0):

### PostScript, 80 bytes

```
00000000: 921a 2f6c 923e 9233 3088 0132 206c 2065  ../l.>.30..2 l e
00000010: 7870 2031 92a9 7b2f 6e92 3e92 335b 3088  xp 1..{/n.>.3[0.
00000020: 016c 2031 92a9 7b6e 2032 926a 3192 3d7b  .l 1..{n 2.j1.={
00000030: 921b 9201 9258 7d7b 9275 7d92 552f 6e20  .....X}{.u}.U/n 
00000040: 6e88 ff92 0f92 337d 9248 5d3d 3d7d 9248  n.....3}.H]==}.H
```

Usage: `gsnd -c 1 2 3 -- powerset.ps` gives output

```
[]
[3]
[2]
[3 2]
[1]
[3 1]
[2 1]
[3 2 1]
```

Un-tokenized version:

```ps
count /l exch def
0 1 2 l exp 1 sub{
    /n exch def
    [
    0 1 l 1 sub{
        n 2 mod 1 eq{
            counttomark add index 
        }{
            pop
        }ifelse
      /n n -1 bitshift def
    }for
    ] ==
}for
```