# Weight balancing problem

Tags: code-golf

Have you ever wondered, when doing shopping, how to pack your products into 2 bags you're carrying so that a total weight would be distributed among them as evenly as possible?

Your task is to write a function, that takes a list of positive numbers (lets say integers for simplicity) as an input. It should return two lists, which:

- Together contain all of the input elements
- The difference of their sums is as close to zero as possible.

The order of returned lists, and their elements is irrelevant.

Here are a couple of test cases:

```
[] -> [[], []]
[1] -> [[1], []]
[1, 1] -> [[1], [1]]
[1, 2, 1] -> [[1, 1], [2]]
[4, 2, 3, 1] -> [[1, 4], [2, 3]]
[3, 8, 1, 5] -> [[1, 8], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! Unfortunately, this problem is essentially a duplicate of [this array partition problem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20210/partition-of-array), which itself is a duplicate of this [subset sum problem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8655/golf-the-subset-sum-problem), so I've marked it thus.

Comment: Edit: I didn't realise my dupe vote was binding, so I've undone my vote in order to let the community decide whether the additional optimisation goal (difference closest to zero rather than exactly zero) is different enough.

Comment: Just found [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51468/help-me-carry-my-shopping-bags), which might be an actual dupe this time?

Comment: Damn. Didn't see that one. I guess mine is a dupe after all.