# Split a number in every possible way

Tags: code-golf, set-partitions

You task here is very simple:
Given a positive integer `n` without leading zeroes as input, split it in all possible ways

### Examples

**Input->Output**

```
111  -> {{111}, {1, 11}, {11, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}

123  -> {{123}, {12, 3}, {1, 23}, {1, 2, 3}}  
  
8451 -> {{8451}, {845, 1}, {8, 451}, {84, 51}, {84, 5, 1}, {8, 45, 1}, {8, 4, 51}, {8, 4, 5, 1}}  

10002-> {{10002},{1,2},{10,2},{100,2},{1000,2},{1,0,2},{10,0,2},{100,0,2},{1,0,0,2},{10,0,0,2},{1,0,0,0,2}}

42690-> {{42690}, {4269, 0}, {4, 2690}, {426, 90}, {42, 690}, {426, 9, 0}, {4, 269, 0}, {4, 2, 690}, {42, 69, 0},  {42, 6, 90}, {4, 26, 90}, {42, 6, 9, 0}, {4, 26, 9, 0}, {4, 2, 69, 0}, {4, 2, 6, 90}, {4, 2, 6, 9,  0}}
```

### Rules

Leading zeroes, if they occur, should be removed.
Duplicate partitions in your final list should also be removed.
The order in which the partitions appear in the final list is irrelevant.

This is `code-golf`. Shortest answer in bytes, wins!

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19258/67961)

Comment: I think would be good question is to compute the power set

Comment: @marshalcraft That [already exists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9045/66833)

Answer (score 10):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
ṫ{~cịᵐ}ᵘ
```

Convert to string `ṫ` and get all unique `{…}ᵘ` reverse concatenations `~c` mapped to integers `ịᵐ` (to remove leading zeros).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9icmFjaHlsb2cy///huat7fmPhu4vhtZB94bWY//8xMDAwMv9a)

Comment: +1 for codegolf spirit

Comment: the output of 101 misses (1,1) which comes from (1, 01)

Comment: @J42161217 Ah, of course! Fixed for +1 byte. Sadly, this makes it quite fast and removes the codegolf spirit. :-)

Comment: Sorry for that..;) +1

Comment: I was going to say "no need to make it faster, it works on my machine if you give it an hour", but it might take that long to even get through the first test case... and I thought I was clever trying `ℕᵐc` as a generator with reversed arguments, but it runs out of global stack instantly! And [`~cℕᵐ`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/3XJj1qmghj/ow0NDXUMjYx1LExMgQwDAwMjHRMjM0uDWAA), which handles the three digit cases fine on TIO, *infinitely repeats the partitions* locally... that's probably my issue with `{~cȧᵐ}ᵘ`, come to think of it, just opaquely

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
.œïÙ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f7@jkw@sPz/z/39DAwMAIAA)

---

#### Explanation

```
.œ      - Partitions of implicit input 
  ï     - Converted to integers (will remove leading 0s) 
   Ù    - Uniquified
        - Output implicitly
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 87 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:{(int(s),)}|{a+b for i in range(1,len(s))for a in f(s[:i])for b in f(s[i:])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDRboMgFIbveYpzV8hoI9gtnUn7IksvbKobiUUiZlnT@ezuHBSL80K/852fA@ju/Vdr83Gsj015u1xL8MWDG9tzL6QYfh/lywXqtgMDxkJX2s@KK9lUFvuCfEm@5v6jMOcgLlGY4iyG0dxc2/Xg754xajfGVpRAsfP91diCAT7GOgnVj4NjSOy8a0zPN9vTRrAYwB6@cVVnHBfBTivwvdigXUc3qPEeTsARA99lwzElxKiUAtie4MGRpJCA1wGlAhBFQzgwpfOY1vmU1hLyOaQXIDeww/5VTWmiEEeYhx4koJychITSfsJLZuL5PFmW6ek8RPP5dfhk8fuESHJRMkkl3bS/0lQMbK/f3rOwbaCwLZGELCD@AdSzlRBRwsqu0kmRxAhjh4plFq1ZDf43b12mY6YyHfRcPfwB)

Comment: This one requires the input to be a string, which I'm not sure is valid? :-)

Comment: @LucasMoeskops, https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18097/91267

Comment: Thanks for the info and sorry for the accusation!

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
{sMM./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v7rY11dP//9/JUMDAwMjJQA)

### Explanation

```
{sMM./
    ./  # Partitions of implicit input
 sMM    # Convert to integers (to remove leading 0s)
{       # Deduplicate
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>136</s> 126 bytes

*Edit: -10 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(s,n=nchar(s))unique(lapply(apply(!combn(rep(1:0,n),n-1),2,which),function(i)as.double(substring(s,c(1,i+1),c(i,n)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5LCgIxEAXP4q4bWzGjK2HOIkkbTUOmJ@aDePoYEQTfonZVvNxLilIv2hbn89xvTbnKqlBIZ@VgMxTEpvJoHqJNKb7gyw2vi1PIPoE5H0iRdGeQJnoG4YD0Kwnasr@uzUUPpblSs@h99BkMyXYoDDL0z/7OgJmOJ@xv)

Hmm... I suspect that this mayn't be the shortest way... but so far my attempts at recursive solutions have been *even* longer...

**Commented code:**

```r
split_number=
function(s,n=nchar(s))                # s=input number (converted to string), n=digits
 unique(                              # output unique values from...
  lapply(                             # ...looping over all... 
   apply(                             # ...combinations of breakpoints by selecting all...
    !combn(rep(1:0,n),n-1),           # ...combinations of TRUE,FALSE at each position...
     1,which),                        # ...and finding indices,
   function(i)                        # ...then, for each combination of breakpoints...
    as.double(                        # ...get numeric value of...
     substring(s,c(1,i+1),c(i,n))     # ...the substrings of the input number
 )
```

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY5LCgIxEAXP4q4bWzGjK2HOIkkbTUOmJ@aDePoYEQTfonZVvNxLilIv2hbn89xvTbnKqlBIZ@VgMxTEpvJoHqJNKb7gyw2vi1PIPoE5H0iRdGeQJnoG4YD0Kwnasr@uzUUPpblSs@h99BkMyXYoDDL0z/7OgJmOJ@xv) by using `combn` since you're taking the `unique` anyway. Not sure about a recursive approach, though.

Comment: Very clever and something that I never would have thought-of!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
ŒṖḌQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7pz3c0RP4//9/EyMzSwMA)

[-1 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210321/split-a-number-in-every-possible-way/210324?noredirect=1#comment495778_210324) thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)

### How it works

```
ŒṖḌQ - Main link. Takes an integer as argument (e.g. n = 42690)
ŒṖ   - Get all partitions. Automatically cast to digits  [[4, 2, 6, 9, 0], [4, 2, 6, [9, 0]], [4, 2, [6, 9], 0], [4, 2, [6, 9, 0]], [4, [2, 6], 9, 0], [4, [2, 6], [9, 0]], [4, [2, 6, 9], 0], [4, [2, 6, 9, 0]], [[4, 2], 6, 9, 0], [[4, 2], 6, [9, 0]], [[4, 2], [6, 9], 0], [[4, 2], [6, 9, 0]], [[4, 2, 6], 9, 0], [[4, 2, 6], [9, 0]], [[4, 2, 6, 9], 0], [4, 2, 6, 9, 0]]
  Ḍ  - Convert each list back to digits                  [[4, 2, 6, 9, 0], [4, 2, 6, 90], [4, 2, 69, 0], [4, 2, 690], [4, 26, 9, 0], [4, 26, 90], [4, 269, 0], [4, 2690], [42, 6, 9, 0], [42, 6, 90], [42, 69, 0], [42, 690], [426, 9, 0], [426, 90], [4269, 0], 42690]
   Q - Remove duplicates                                 [[4, 2, 6, 9, 0], [4, 2, 6, 90], [4, 2, 69, 0], [4, 2, 690], [4, 26, 9, 0], [4, 26, 90], [4, 269, 0], [4, 2690], [42, 6, 9, 0], [42, 6, 90], [42, 69, 0], [42, 690], [426, 9, 0], [426, 90], [4269, 0], 42690]
      - Implicit output
```

Comment: The leading`D` is redundant since `partitions(array)` performs an `array = iterable(array, make_digits = True)` upfront. (the wiki text "Partition of z (z must be a list)." is somewhat misleading)

Comment: @JonathanAllan So it can, I never realised that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <sup><s>139</s>...<s>104</s></sup> 94 bytes

```scala
def f(? :String):Set[_]=Set(?)++(for{< <-1 to?.size-1
x<-f(?take<)
y<-f(?drop<)}yield x+","+y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BboMwDIbveQor2iEWo0pYW20oFdpxh516rKaJFjOxsoCIDzDGs9OIoV7s77f0@feXvM7n5vxNF4b3vHJAPZMrPLy2LYxzQSWUKoP0yF3lvjA9Ep8@Pw5hqQyjSJVNN1qwsQFuso2vfik2ordxkDi/kkUxLKHomtbiNFRUF9BH8lFGAy7vmTwrn8KbY4QDtKGHa6dK5eWDl7j5uf53KzkGC/4gzEkiCrGYRhtcydwpeVrpebu7H7XWycrbZP@iUUzzDQ)

A recursive method. The input has to be a string.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=uniq -F`, <s>108</s> <s>96</s> <s>94</s> 90 bytes

```perl
say uniq map{@b=(sprintf'%b',$_)=~/./g;$_="@F
";s/ /','x pop@b/ge;s/\d+/$&*1/reg}1..2**$#F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKhNC@zUCE3saDaIclWo7igKDOvJE1dNUldRyVe07ZOX08/3Vol3lbJwY1LybpYX0FfXUe9QqEgv8AhST89FSgSk6Ktr6KmZahflJpea6inZ6SlpaLs9v@/oYGBgdG//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYGQNons7jEyiq0JDPHFmT1f103AA)

Comment: Building on your solution, I was able to cut 22 bytes in 
 
 https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKhNC@zUCE3sUDJwY1LybauuEahRiVe39bIWl1HvUJDJV7VSLOmKDUdJBOTol2joqZlCOLrGOrpGWlpObj9/29oYGBg9C@/oCQzP6/4v66vqZ6BoQGQ9sksLrGyCi3JzLEFWfJf1w0A

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 59 bytes

```
\G\d
$&$'¶$`,$&
+%)`^.+¶

m`^,|\b0+\B

O`
m`^(.+)(¶\1)+$
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qoeGe8D/GPSaFS0VNRf3QNpUEHRU1Lm1VzYQ4Pe1D27i4chPidGpikgy0Y5y4uPwTQHwNPW1NjUPbYgw1tVW4VAz//zc0NOQyNDLmsjAxBTIMDAyMuEyMzCwNAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\G\d
$&$'¶$`,$&
```

Create copies of the line with all possible proper prefixes of the first number on the line.

```
^.+¶
```

If there were any such prefixes, delete the original line.

```
+%)`
```

Repeat until no more prefixes can be generated.

```
m`^,|\b0+\B
```

Remove the leading separator and also leading zeros of any numbers.

```
O`
m`^(.+)(¶\1)+$
$1
```

Sort and deduplicate the results.

For the Retina 1 port, the biggest saving comes from deduplication, which is basically a built-in in Retina 1. The newlines aren't included in the deduplication, so another stage is needed to filter out blank lines, but it's still a saving of 14 bytes. Another 3 bytes can be saved by using `$"` which is a shorthand for `` $'¶$` ``. I also tried using an `L` stage to avoid leaving the original line but then a conditional is required to end the loop which means that the byte count ends up unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 81 bytes

```python
f=lambda g:{(int(g),)}|{b+(int(g[i:]),)for i in range(1,len(g))for b in f(g[:i])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBboMwDIbveQrfmmhpRUJXdUjti0w9UBW6SDSNAE2rOp6d2QmhYRzg8@8vjoV79F93m49jfWjK2/lSwrV4cmN7fhVSDL/P81uoPk1xwqS@t2DAWGhLe624kk1lUfX5mfIa1cKcxDCam7u3PXSPjjFqN8ZWZGCw6fqLsQUDfIx1EqofBwdvbDrXmJ6v1seVYFHAHr7xVGscFz4NJ/A9pz52LW1b485OwAGF77LhaAkxKqUA1kd4ciQpJOD2oJQHopgQDkzpPNo6D7aWkE@SnoGyge237yrYRF5HmIbuJWAYMgkJpf2EZyfwtE@WZTrsQzTtr/0ni98XRJJzJBMr6ab9RUzFwLZ695H5az35a4kkZB7xD2A8pRIiSlikCzspEo0wdqiYZ9GZxeB/85ZlOiaU6aDX6eEP)

Comment: You can take input as a string as long as you get the correct results without leading zeroes. Please provide a TIO link so that anyone can test your code.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I made the TIO, and saw that my answer was incorrect so I made some adjustments, so it is now 81 bytes instead of 79, but gives the correct answer to all examples.

Comment: nice +1. Welcome to code golf!

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ã
cU à f_¬¥NÃ®mnÃâ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4wpjVSDgIGZfrKVOw65tbsPi&input=IjEwMDQiCi1R)

- Saved 1 thanks to @Shaggy !

```
    ã                  - substrings of input
      cUã)             - concatenated to substrings of input(repeated)
          à            - combinations
            f_¬¥N      - take combinatons if == input when joined
           ®mn  - deduplicates ( @Shaggy ® )
                    Ãâ    - implicitly returns unique elements
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output be deduplicated?

Comment: Deduplicating after the map would get around that for `+0`bytes: `ã cUã)à f_¬¥UÃ®mnÃâ`.

Comment: [18 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4wpjVSDgIGZfrKVOw65tbsPi&input=IjEwMDQiCi1R)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 47 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦Ｓ⟧≔⟦⟧θＦυ«≔⊟ιη¿ηＦＬη⊞υ⁺ι⟦Ｉ…η⊕κ✂η⊕κ⟧¿¬№θι⊞θι»Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@9CsIwFIVn@xR3vBciVFcn6SSIFDqWDiXGJhiTtkkEEZ893opujofz83Gk7mfpe5tznYLGJKA9uDHFJs7GDUgd7Yp9CGZw2HYCJpYXPwMmgmex@jq1H9GQAM3uylwANcEndVRuiJolwW@@timgYUzVh4jVQ1pVae5rAQcnZ3VTLqozXol4sLFGqj9WRwtJ2aBgwZ08L/nkIk4CDP1oH7ErXkXNXzixACdu5rwpy3Kb13f7Bg) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦Ｓ⟧
```

Start a breadth first search with the input number.

```
≔⟦⟧θ
```

Start with no results.

```
Ｆυ«
```

Loop over the candidates.

```
≔⊟ιη
```

Get the current suffix.

```
¿ηＦＬη
```

If the suffix is not empty then loop over all of its proper suffixes...

```
⊞υ⁺ι⟦Ｉ…η⊕κ✂η⊕κ⟧
```

... push the next candidate, which is the prefixes so far, the current prefix cast to integer, and the current suffix.

```
¿¬№θι⊞θι
```

But if it is empty and the resulting split is unique then push it to the results.

```
»Ｉθ
```

Print all the results. (This uses Charcoal's default output, whereby lists are double-spaced as their entries are printed on separate lines.)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>36</sup> 29 bytes

```
[:~.]<@("./.~+/\)"#.2#:@i.@^#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o63q9GJtHDSU9PT16rT1YzSVlPWMlK0cMvUc4pT/a3JxpSZn5CukKagbGhmrIzgGBgZGCK6JkZmlgfp/AA)

*-7 bytes thank to xash!*

Explanation later.

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o63q9GJtHDSU9PT16rT1YzSVlPWMlK0cMvUc4pT/a3L5OekpIKvRVDKsMwSqcwCq0Y62ytQzilPWNbRCqNOItrLBpzA1OSNfIU1B3dDIWB3BMTAwMEJwTYzMLA3U/wMA)

Comment: Great edits.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 38 bytes

```perl6
{unique +<<m:ex/^(.+)+$/>>[0],:as(~*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/ujQvs7A0VUHbxibXKrVCP05DT1tTW0Xfzi7aIFbHKrFYo05Ls/Z/cWKlgh5QQ1p@kUJOZl5q8X9DQ0MuQyNjLgsTUyDDwMDAiMvEyMzSAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 106 bytes

```
Union@Table[FromDigits/@#~TakeList~i,{i,Join@@Permutations/@IntegerPartitions@Length@#}]&@IntegerDigits@#&
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NYwxC8IwEEZ/TKBTodFduEEEpUOGOoUMp1zTQ3OB9Jyk/euxKK7fe@9LqBMlVL5jHQ/1KpwFBrw9yZ9KTkeOrHMHZh3wQT3PunL75vaSWQAclfTSLc6yOWdRilQcFuXvBD1J1AnMEpo//R2CaaorLOpHv7PW7kOoHw)

Comment: [98 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYyxCsIwFEV3v0IodG1aq@hQeIMISocMOoUMQUL6KHmB5Ln212NRwXY899x7veHBesP4NNl1@UEYSF1i8Gd0yKmCNN3NaHtMPBVlBbeABCBt9C@eV4HmypXYOhuliYyfCHpLjgeVup/6nkGhdZllROItOFWLWm/@VK@o2S3o2O5XUgjRLLhtDiehc34D "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")  This was also my approach. You can save some bytes if you don't use `Table`

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

Expects a string. Returns a Set of comma-separated strings.

```javascript
f=([c,...a],o='',S=new Set)=>c?f(a,o+c,o?f(a,o+[,c],S):S):S.add(o.replace(/\d+/g,n=>+n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcpBCsIwEIXhvaeQbprQMU1qFRVSD9Fl7SJMkqKUTGmLHj8quJLAW/x8vId5mgXn@7TuAlkXo9esQxBCmB5I5zm0OrjXtnUr1w1ePTNABQL9qgPsoeWX74SxlpGY3TQadKy82aIcIOimCJxHpLDQ6MRIA/MsU0plnG/@tdon9FQfkmcpZZXwujqe5cfjGw)

#### How?

It's important to note that `Set.prototype.add()` returns the set itself. And because the recursion always ends with `S.add(...)`, each call to `f` returns `S`.

#### Commented

*NB: alternate slash symbols used in the regular expression to prevent the syntax highlighting from being broken*

```javascript
f = (                // f is a recursive function taking:
  [c,                //   c   = next digit character
      ...a],         //   a[] = array of remaining digits
  o = '',            //   o   = output string
  S = new Set        //   S   = set of solutions
) =>                 //
  c ?                // if c is defined:
    f(               //   do a recursive call:
      a,             //     pass a[]
      o + c,         //     append c to o
      o ?            //     if o is non-empty:
        f(           //       do another recursive call
          a,         //         pass a[]
          o + [, c], //         append a comma followed by c to o
          S          //         pass S
        )            //       end of recursive call (returns S)
      :              //     else:
        S            //       just pass S as the 3rd argument
    )                //   end of recursive call (returns S)
  :                  // else:
    S.add(           //   add to the set S:
      o.replace(     //     the string o with ...
        ∕\d+∕g,      //       ... all numeric strings
        n => +n      //       coerced to integers to remove leading zeros
                     //       (and coerced back to strings)
      )              //     end of replace()
    )                //   end of add() (returns S)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>32</s> 25 bytes

-4 bytes from not de-listing first result

-3 bytes from @ngn's improvements

```
{?.''(&'+1,!1_2&$x)_\:$x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqtpeT11dQ01d21BH0TDeSE2lQjM@xkqlovZ/mrqhoaGCoZGxgoWJKZBhYGBgpGBiZGZp8B8A)

- `&'+1,!1_2&$x` returns the subset of the (power set of indices of the input) that begin with 0. The original power set index generation code was taken from [@JohnE's answer on a different question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51634/98547), and includes improvements from @ngn's comments on this answer.
- `(...)_\:$x` `cut`s the stringified-input on each of the specified indices
- `?.''` converts each slice to integers, taking the `distinct` elements

Comment: well golfed! small improvement: `2|^$x` -> `2&$x`

Comment: i think enlisting the first item should be fine. the examples enclose it with `{` `}` which implies it's a list.

Comment: to avoid the expensive "filter": `(~*:)#&'+!2&$` -> `&'+1,!1_2&$`

Comment: @ngn: much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 127 bytes

```ruby
->(n,f=->(s){s.size.times.map{|i|([f.(s[0...i])].flatten(i>1?1:0).map{|j|[j.flatten<<s[i..-1]]})}.flatten(2)}){f.(n.to_i.to_s)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUzbCsIgGL7fU/wMBgruR@1ARa0HEYkVGzmaSdpFTZ99raJuvgPf4XY/Pka3G8uKWNbuJvJ08OjNs8Fg@sZjX7shmkhUi8QrjohGU43tpQ6hscRUYi82nH57XVTdL9puvTKIpdA60fQfSJroMH1ZDNeDeYOnaVRCCJYJOWPZar54S865ZNlcLtecZfnkPjLX2NSnMwwQbQR3D57khYOygsLlUICyDJyyWlNI4ws)

**Explanation**

1. first lambda takes a number and a function as parameters
2. second parameter defaults to the lambda that computes the partition
3. the second lambda is called with the number stripped of leading zeroes
4. computation starts with a map for each split point in the number
5. recursively call lambda for the substring before the split point
6. append the substring after the split point to each resulting partition array

judicious array creation [] and applications of flatten in the code ensure exactly one level of array nesting in the result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 87 bytes

```perl
sub f{$_=pop;/(.)(.+)/?do{my$s=$1;map s/@_\d+/0+$&/ger,map{("$s $_",$s.$_)}f(1,$2)}:$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLLbsIwELzzFaPIbW3hkjhQRIlC8wO99QYoosJUtIREMZUaRfl2ajsvUDk1h93x7MzsHpLJ/PB0Pqvvd@xKEodZmgUuHTE6GjL3ZZuWSUFUSESQbDIoN4pX26HrDcm9@yFzrsmSOkSBxA4nakRiVu2o4MRn1ZzE1flbSbxJdZrPX9Nc4qShChfTYJAUiMwrpANgKYQAwgWWjkYOhyPQdA2atwbrNbdqf9yq/bGd@qg7/LZr4l/q2eRJ1GqDzFj3@oYZOgY9MDNt7D@r6xytErW0vcnzPL@@ySCHmyNM9ZrW9QbA9us9WtzLe13L4Zo0uNk@8afPnt1ukbnPANQIFxxaBMtd77fzC1MHMb2w4YYPXTCudlzG4ZYTbWKD@5jGvF6DBYNdmlP7d7HSBiQFJftjxon8yVgYkThoaNxpJoh0KSMzrEIq2I@Qfi/4SE9BpEu5sxnsr4SYTcdNIkPHKPC4gDP6TPdH@sDxwFWan@iXLJSJYqy27VW8lTI7FHRlaI6VuYT3WVpXnX8B)

Ungolfed:

```perl
sub f {
  $_ = pop;                     # set $_ to input (last arg)
  if( /(.)(.+)/ ) {             # if input two or more digits, split
                                # into start digit and rest
    my $s = $1;                 # store start digit
    return
      map s/@_\d+/0+$&/ger,     # no @_ => 1st recursive level => trim leading 0s
                                # 0+$& means int(digits matched)
      map { ("$s $_", "$s$_") } # return "start+space+rest" and "start+rest"...
      f(1, $2)                  # ...for every result of rest
                                # (1 marks recursive level below first)
  }
  else {
    return $_                   # if just one digit, return that
  }
}
```

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -MList::Util, 68 bytes

...which is further golfed from the answer from @xcali

```perl
say uniq map"@F
"=~s| |$_/=2;','x($_%2)|reg=~s|\d+|$&*1|reg,1..2**@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKhNC@zUCE3sUDJwY1LybauuEahRiVe39bIWl1HvUJDJV7VSLOmKDUdJBOTol2joqZlCOLrGOrpGWlpObj9/29oYGBg9C@/oCQzP6/4v66vqZ6BoQGQ9sksLrGyCi3JzLEFWfJf1w0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
ummdf(=d¹Σ)ṖQd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/vzQ3NyVNwzbl0M5zizUf7pwWmPL//39DA0MA)

Comment: If you input 101, this returns `[[1,0,1],[10,1],[0,10,1],[1,1],[0,1,1],[101],[0,101]]` while it should return `[[101],[1,1],[10,1],[1,0,1]]`

Comment: @J42161217 corrected it

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 44 bytes

```
YaUQ({(a|>0)RMx}M({y=aRMs?a^sx}M(PMaJs)))RMx
```

Probably my craziest Pip answer. There's definitely a shorter method, but I decided to roll with this.

-p pretty prints the final list for easier verification. Takes a very long time with 5 digit numbers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@G@tEBqoUV1pmxjkW2wfnVhTUxxbUeurEeCb6FWsCeQFlRdr/o9MBCnSSKyxM9AM8gXJw3QkxhUjlGuCJP///29oZPxftwAA)

### Explanation

```
YaUQ({(a|>0)RMx}M({y=aRMs?a^sx}M(PMaJs)))RMx a → first command line argument
Ya                                           Yank a into variable y
                                 PMaJs       join each element of a with a space, get permutations
                  {y=aRMs?a^sx}M             filter out the permutations that are not in order
     {(a|>0)RMx}M                            Strip leading zeros and empty strings in each split
                                         RMx remove empty strings from the whole result
  UQ                                         print the unique splits
```