# Divisor chain counts (1 3 3 7 ...)

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, division

The [divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor#Definition) of a natural number form a [poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) under the [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)) of "a divides b?", \$a | b\$. This challenge is to produce the number, \$C\$, of non-empty [chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Chains) of such posets for natural numbers, \$N\$.

This is [A253249](https://oeis.org/A253249) in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

That may sound complicated, but it's not really, let's look at an...

##### Example

For \$N=28\$ the divisors are \$\{1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28\}\$ and the number of non-empty chains is \$C(28) = 31\$. The non-empty chains are these subsets of those divisors:

$$\{1\}, \{2\}, \{4\}, \{7\}, \{14\}, \{28\}$$
$$\{1, 2\}, \{1, 4\}, \{1, 7\}, \{1, 14\}, \{1, 28\}, \{2, 4\},$$
$$\{2, 14\}, \{2, 28\}, \{4, 28\}, \{7, 14\}, \{7, 28\}, \{14, 28\}$$
$$\{1, 2, 4\}, \{1, 2, 14\}, \{1, 2, 28\}, \{1, 4, 28\}, \{1, 7, 14\},$$
$$\{1, 7, 28\}, \{1, 14, 28\}, \{2, 4, 28\}, \{2, 14, 28\}, \{7, 14, 28\},$$
$$\{1, 2, 4, 28\}, \{1, 2, 14, 28\}, \{1, 7, 14, 28\}$$

These chains are those non-empty subsets of \$\{1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28\}\$ such that all pairs of elements \$\{a, b\}\$ satisfy either \$a|b\$ or \$b|a\$ - that is one is a divisor of the other.

Since \$2\$ does not divide \$7\$ **and** \$7\$ does not divide \$2\$, no chain has a subset of \$\{2, 7\}\$.

Similarly no chain has a subset of either \$\{4, 7\}\$ or \$\{4, 14\}\$.

Furthermore the empty chain, \$\emptyset = \{\}\$, is not counted.

##### I/O

You may take input and give output using [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) [defaults](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info).
\$N\$ is guaranteed to be a positive integer, \$N \ge 1\$.

##### Tests

The first \$360\$ values are:

```
1, 3, 3, 7, 3, 11, 3, 15, 7, 11, 3, 31, 3, 11, 11, 31, 3, 31, 3, 31, 11, 11, 3, 79, 7, 11, 15, 31, 3, 51, 3, 63, 11, 11, 11, 103, 3, 11, 11, 79, 3, 51, 3, 31, 31, 11, 3, 191, 7, 31, 11, 31, 3, 79, 11, 79, 11, 11, 3, 175, 3, 11, 31, 127, 11, 51, 3, 31, 11, 51, 3, 303, 3, 11, 31, 31, 11, 51, 3, 191, 31, 11, 3, 175, 11, 11, 11, 79, 3, 175, 11, 31, 11, 11, 11, 447, 3, 31, 31, 103, 3, 51, 3, 79, 51, 11, 3, 303, 3, 51, 11, 191, 3, 51, 11, 31, 31, 11, 11, 527, 7, 11, 11, 31, 15, 175, 3, 255, 11, 51, 3, 175, 11, 11, 79, 79, 3, 51, 3, 175, 11, 11, 11, 831, 11, 11, 31, 31, 3, 175, 3, 79, 31, 51, 11, 175, 3, 11, 11, 447, 11, 191, 3, 31, 51, 11, 3, 527, 7, 51, 31, 31, 3, 51, 31, 191, 11, 11, 3, 703, 3, 51, 11, 79, 11, 51, 11, 31, 79, 51, 3, 1023, 3, 11, 51, 103, 3, 175, 3, 303, 11, 11, 11, 175, 11, 11, 31, 191, 11, 299, 3, 31, 11, 11, 11, 1007, 11, 11, 11, 175, 11, 51, 3, 447, 103, 11, 3, 175, 3, 51, 51, 79, 3, 175, 11, 31, 11, 51, 3, 1471, 3, 31, 63, 31, 31, 51, 11, 79, 11, 79, 3, 703, 11, 11, 51, 511, 3, 51, 11, 175, 31, 11, 3, 527, 11, 51, 11, 31, 3, 527, 3, 191, 51, 11, 31, 175, 3, 11, 31, 527, 3, 51, 3, 31, 51, 51, 11, 2175, 7, 51, 11, 31, 3, 175, 11, 79, 79, 11, 11, 703, 11, 11, 11, 191, 11, 175, 3, 175, 11, 51, 3, 527, 3, 11, 175, 31, 3, 51, 11, 1023, 11, 51, 11, 831, 31, 11, 11, 79, 11, 299, 3, 31, 31, 11, 11, 1471, 3, 31, 11, 175, 11, 175, 15, 79, 51, 11, 3, 175, 3, 175, 79, 447, 3, 51, 11, 31, 51, 11, 3, 2415
```

##### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to make code in as few bytes as possible in your language of choice. Your score is the number of bytes of your program or function.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
ÆḌƬFLḤ’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVQ7TgMxEL0KoqbwZ2cdX4CKa6RBuQAdooCGC1DRUOYA20fiHpuLGDz22G9sRcomsT2f99487/PxdHpJ6fK@b5@/58enffu5vn6ly8f17bxv3/cp@dUk@3Dn@RP425a1Jd6oK2/bGe@oXW/h5D8rtsxcpAZR@VmhCj/Gq8o5uUd726vnoGgLSg0j50gu4LCBOqG87Soq0rBlCUiwL0FvP1RHJhV520dV8rMsQXOq/aiToF7ewylXiFat/dCBMrmgJ5TVFxEckaaD8HliSviJ3UENuWsv9TndAl4Qv7FHIhjsO37S5WXJWeixQR4ZPcojimYUxvXhEtquwmS5lS9RAIXAxTi5vjjZhBs1KoqigfGTQ6nG3LKQsFhC124FK40q1DoBSZUe2kSl/zCEUUbZlzuAZ@MVk0DSM5YUx/Fhqt8IixGbMaexxNFfg8YNKtJDyuwE5HgYr5IAwEGrYeMYtFf4D02XWYHNZ/IuQB0g3i2W/gA)

```
  Ƭ        Loop while unique:
ÆḌ         Recursively vectorizing proper divisors (empty list if 1).
  ƬF       Deep flatten the full history of results,
    L      take the length,
     Ḥ     double (to account for the chains including the original n),
      ’    and decrement (to not double count the trivial chain of just {n}).
```

Comment: Nice. I had something similar but with an extra `Ẏ$` because I’d not taken advantage of `ÆḌ` vectorising down to the deepest level.

Comment: Interestingly this is also similar to the Maple solution in the linked OEIS, except that one would be closer to `ÆDÆḌƬFL` which is the same byte count.

Comment: @NickKennedy Regarding both of your comments, you might find the edit history amusing :P

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 45 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,d=1:d//n or-~f(d)*(n%d<1)+f(n,d+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVTLTsMwEDzDV/iClNCiZuNs3VT0Y4pCoBK4VdQLF349xI@1dx0hNW3tfXhmdpzbz/3zavXhNs3zePo6f78NZ2W3wwmOw25n1XV6@R2roX6u7NPwCvVmrJboBup5vE7KqotV09l@vFewbaE@Pj7cpou9LzlqSazrGbZK@4/x3xDWgH4jrjSkmN8RuxpYZKnqU6VrEpMw/OxZF/80WnR2xTlbQ@7uknoIKCUMV0O1DAcYzITcdhtRoYRNS4aEn4vsbF1050wi8rTPVXFP1xnJKZ6HmQTm9ppFfYcexFoXJ6AjZ@SEnPokQoso6XD4fmJC@BW7gxhy1p76@3JgeJn4iT0nwpN1xo@yPS19FfdYIQ@NnstDijoUTZuHi9x2EaaXW/iSCyAQtH2/cn1wcmP@6RFRBA0avXIoxpz/LEQsOpO12zMrlSrEPoaTCmdIE4XziyGUMtI@3QEeK68YJaKcMZW0Pt@s@ifCZMRkzNVY@tJfhcYJKqfHKXsncI6H8ioRAD5oMWw@BukV/wdXl1mAdTF6F3AdWH7bAf4B)

**51 bytes**

```python
f=lambda n:1+sum(1+f(d)for d in range(1,n)if n%d<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVTLbsIwEDy3X5FLpURwyMZZTFD7MVRpWqRiUKCHfn1aO9541hESAex9eGZ2nOvv/evizP46TtPw9n08v/fHwh1oc/s5l7QZyr4aLmPRFydXjEf3@VHS1lWnoXAv/StVkw86DJodVYfnp@t4cvfSbYuhdFU10bYw4WPDN81r4rARV4aWWNhRu4Yg8l/VLZW@SUzi@WcHXcJTG9XZF6dsQ6m7T@poRqlh@BqpBRxkORHy201ExRq2LAEJnstwtsm6I5OIfNlHVfzTtlZziudxIsGpvYFo6NCRWpvsBPbkrJ6QV19EaJg1HYQfJqaEX7HbqyEn7aV/KCfAC@Iv7JEIJpuEn3V7WYYq9Fgmj4we5RFFPYq6ScNltF2EGeRWvkQBFIKm61aun51c2wc9IopZg9qsHMox55GFhEVrk3Y7sFKuQuxjkdR8hjbRfH42hFxG2Zc7gLH8ikki6xlLSRPy7ar/QliMuBhzNZYu91em8QIV6SHl4ATkuM@vkgDAQath4xi0V8IfXl1mBdbH5F2AOkB@0xL/AQ)

Answer (score 6):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-n`, 6 bytes

```
ĎSᵉti¦
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJunlLsgqWlJWm6FquO9AU_3NpZknlo2ZLipORiqPCCm0aGXEZcxlwmXKZcZlzmXBZcllyGBlyGhlyGRlyGxlyGJlyGplyGZlyG5lyGFlyGllxGBhCtAA)

```
ĎSᵉti¦
Ď       Divisors
 S      Find a subset such that
  ᵉt      removing the first element
     ¦    is divisible by
    i     removing the last element
```

`-n` counts the number of solutions.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 44 bytes

```r
`?`=\(n,d=1)`if`(d<n,(n?d+1)+(1+?d)*!n%%d,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3dRLsE2xjNPJ0UmwNNRMy0xI0UmzydDTy7FO0DTW1NQy17VM0tRTzVFVTdAw1IXq2pGkYGmhyFScWFORUahhaGRnopEGlFiyA0AA)

Port of [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265927/55372).

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
ÑæʒRüÖP}g<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MTDy05NCjq85/C0gNp0m///DU0A)

```
Ñ      # divisors of N
æ      # subsets
ʒ      # keep those such that
 R      # when reversed
 üÖ     # whether each term divides the previous one?
 P      # all
}
g      # and take the length
<      # -1
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), <s>63</s> 54 bytes

### (#2)

Thanks to @att for the massive –9 bytes!

```rust
fn f(n:i64)->i64{(1..n).fold(1,|a,d|a-(1>>n%d)*!f(d))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZTPTsMgHMcP3voUbMmSH13LxvwTU7e-yLIY5kpC0tKl0HmAvoN3LzvoA_g4-jRCW52HJeoyDhB-4fvhE1p4fqlqpfcfF29cooIJCRiZSYjyTCOOFiiwMqlvrqypVYaEzipdlrlKkvAOKCELiQkXuSuD3Vg52iwWU0y25WNWqUwDJkLq8t7H4LBQWUX60jarilozLUqpYIYJy3OwO7tbTlfpbklX1vp-5OeejMlDWUvHjWnzT7E5PZPXyBuF31qOez6rs5q47yn5FFofHKeuN97hmELBtn5Gxxw2DqLqAnAL4PRUQJLMXSAFPO5U-OwkEi_zDdDIsmht2XjdW13-jXUIeyDrkB3h6jjhR0Bw1GLMV7LJcpUZ1nwR6D8Ih_y0GbOecP2rA9CYksLdScfBOIT-VFpCOHmtNY9v3288y5FESxLHSSwGmqYeEw66Y-jTT0HAywoJJCTyf-jsFpkA9W1buXuSywEMOZgGu-fANMMIichtKDC-axc2QTv8QnEM00RoeCz6vY0r9177fTd-Ag)

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 63 bytes

### (#0)

Originally based on [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265927/109946). Straightforward functional implementation of their idea.

```rust
fn f(n:u64)->u64{(1..n).filter(|d|n%d<1).fold(1,|a,d|1+a+f(d))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZTPbsIgHMcPu_UpmIkJ9A-Kc4upf_Ygxiw4S0LSUlOoO0DfYfddPGwPsMfZnmbQVt3BxOnkAOEXvh8-oYW396KUavt988kEyCgXEAHd80GaKMDAFHhGxOXD0OhSJoCrpFB5nso49seQYDwVCDOe2jI0KyO6q-m0j_A6f0kKmSiIMBcqf3IxeFgojcRtaZ0UWamo4rmQcIAwTVNoNmYz7y9mmzlZGOP6rps7MsLPeSksNyLVmWITciWvrjPy91qWez2rq5rY7ylYH9Y-KJrZXjuHYwoZXbsZCRhcWYgsM4hqACOXAuJ4YgMziIJGhQ0uIrE8XUESGhouDQ2WrdXd31iHsAPSBtkQhscJvwKcgRqjd8kqSWWiabUjkDMIh3y_CmhLuD_pAElEcGbvpOUg5MP2VGqC3_soFYtGX4-O9Y_zaDGvnsfyAnDABXC_6mAEtAfati7shUnFLewwqCtk3wVddULAQ7szR2hcL6y8ejhBsQxdhaBzLLrfxpZbr-22GX8A)

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 63 bytes

### (#1)

Works just like #0, but the filter is inlined into the fold.

```rust
fn f(n:u64)->u64{(1..n).fold(1,|a,d|if n%d<1{1+f(d)}else{0}+a)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZQ7bsIwHIeHbjmFi4Rk52EwpRUKjx4EocqUWLKUOCh26GDnDt27MLQH6HHa09ROAnRAolAy2PJf_n3-5Efe3otSqu33zScTIKNcQAR0zwdpogADU-AZEZcPQ6NLmQCukkLleSrj2B9DgvFUIMx4asvQrIzorqbTPsLr_CUpZKIgwlyo_MnF4GGiNBK3pXVSZKWiiudCwgHCNE2h2ZjNvL-YbeZkYYxru27syAg_56Ww3IhUZ4pNyJW8us7I32tZ7vWsrmpiz1OwPqx9UDSzrXYOxxQyunYjEjC4shBZZhDVAEYuBcTxxAZmEAWNChtcRGJ5uoIkNDRcGhosW6u7v7EOYQekDbIhDI8TfgU4AzVG75JVkspE02pHIGcQDvl-FdCWcH_SAZKI4My-SctByIftrtQEv_dRKhaNvh4d6x8uLebV81heAA64AO6qDkZAe6D91oV9MKm4hR0GdYXsf0FXnRDw0K7MERrXEyuv7k5QLENXIegci-6XseXWa7tt-h8)

Previous attempts and ideas can be found in the ATO links. It took me a while to realize that the descriptive symbolic idea of using itertools, powerset and so on looks extremely cool but just isn't suited for code golf at all if less readable solutions exist.

They all work the same way, with the exception that the first two functions evaluate recursively lazily and the last one eagerly (Infinite recursion is prevented by not calling the closure when the iterator is empty, providing this as a base case). The performance difference is noticeable. <s>I'm sure there must be a way to golf one of these even further (more likely the latter two than the former).</s> It's quite likely that the golfing potential has now been exhausted.

Comment: `fn f(n:i64)->i64{(1..n).fold(1,|a,d|a-(1>>n%d)*!f(d))}`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

*-11 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!*

Returns the \$n\$-th term.

```javascript
f=(n,d=n)=>d--&&f(n,d)-!(n%d)*~f(d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCsIwEEX3PcUItcy0RlBwVcezNDSJKGFG2uImpFePcfXfg8d/269d5@X12Yyo86UERjk5FuKHM6brwl/JHFCOjvo9oKMSdMHoNxBguIx17gzXW4VhIEgNwKyyavTnqE@cLLZJMtW2TfWN8kRjk8sP)

Or [try a faster version](https://tio.run/##FcvBCsIwDADQXwkDR4JtmAgelE78DhEpyyobWzI6Ebz461WP7/DG@Iprl4fl6dWkLyUFVCdBKbTifV2nP8mjbuTcHD8Jhah0pqtNPU/2wCszX3KOb9wfGrrxHBfEuwMlCC38OmxhR8SjDYqVg4roVL4) (36 bytes) that generates the 360 first values listed in the challenge.

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (        // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,         //   n = input
  d = n      //   d = current divisor candidate
) =>         //
d-- &&       // if d is not 0 (decrement it afterwards):
  f(n, d) -  //   do a 1st recursive call with the updated d
  !(n % d) * //   test whether d is a divisor of n
             //   if not, ignore the result of ...
  ~f(d)      //   ... a 2nd recursive call with n = d
             //   (otherwise, increment the final count)
```

Comment: `f=(n,d=n)=>d--&&f(n,d)+(n%d?0:1+f(d))` is both shorter and faster. Ported from my Charcoal answer.

Comment: `f=(n,d=n)=>d--&&f(n,d)-(n%d?0:~f(d))` is a byte shorter. `f=(n,d=n)=>d--&&f(n,d)-!(n%d)*~f(d)` is a further byte shorter but back to being inefficient.

Comment: @Neil Ugh. Much better indeed! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,p=n)=>--p?f(n,p)+!(n%p)*-~f(p):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBCsIwEEX3PcUIFWaMESq4aR29SkObiBImoS1uQnr1GFf/PXj8j/madVrecdMSZluKY5RzZCF@aB2f7m@kDijHSCe9O4zUd8WFBb3dQIChG@rcGa63CkoRpAZgCrIGby8@vHA02CbJVNs21UPKIw1NLj8)

Found independent, I'd just leave it here

Comment: [`f=(n,p=n)=>p&&f(n,--p)-!(n%p)*~f(p)`](https://tio.run/##JYrBDoJADAXv/oUHSZ@4Gzhj@RHjYYPUrCFtA8YT8ddXiKfJTOaVPmkZ5uzvoPYYSxEmvTgruPeqkk1CcIQj6clx/go59ke4pxhj2ja5pfu60g6WfwRIcBCbKXPb5WvbNF2uawymi01jnOxJQhkoPw)

Comment: @tsh Rolled back as Arnauld applied it earlier

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 18 bytes

```
∧+1+1∵(|1↬2)⊚=0◿⇡.
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oinKzErMeKItSh8MSDihqwyKeKKmj0w4pe_4oehLgoKZiAyOAriiLVmICsxIOKHoSAyMA==)

```
∧+1+1∵(|1↬2)⊚=0◿⇡.  input: a positive integer n
⊚=0◿⇡.   proper divisors of n:
  ◿⇡.       n modulo (each of) range of n
  ⊚=0       indices of zeros
∵(|1↬2)  recurse on each
+1         add 1 to each result
∧+1       sum the results and add 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 34 bytes

```
.+
$*
+%M!&`^|(1+$)(?<=^\1\1+)|$
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLS1vVV1EtIa5Gw1BbRVPD3sY2LsYwxlBbs0aF69C2//8NuYy4jLlMuEy5zLjMuSy4LLkMDbgMDbkMjbgMjbkMTbgMTQE) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+%M!&`^|(1+$)(?<=^\1\1+)|$
```

Calculate \$ A253249(i) = 1 + \sum_{j|i} 1 + A253249(j) \$. The `+%` repeatedly processes inner terms until they become empty. The `!&` outputs overlapping matches. The `(1+$)(?<=^\1\1+)` matches factors of \$ i \$, and the leading and trailing empty match applies the two \$ 1 + \$ terms somehow... not quite sure how that works, but I'm not complaining. The result is actually the number of newlines generated by the repeated factorisation.

```
¶
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>79</s> 38 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{1+(1...n).sum{|r|1[n%r]*-~f[r]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6v2lBbw1BPTy9PU6@4NLe6pqjGMDpPtShWS7cuLbootrb2P0ja0MBAUy83saC6prCmQCEtujC29j8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＦＮ⊞υ↨Ｅι∧¬∧κ﹪ικ⊕§υκ¹Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxDsIwDEDRnVN4tKUwVEgsnQpTh1a9QkiMWjV1qiRG3D6Q6Q9P@m61yUUban3HBDjKqWXW48UJiWDRvKIaeNjMONkTNwODeJxjwdbdwBS9hthgJyIDo7jEB0thj0MZxfO3HRr@taP@sqRNCj5tLqhEfa23e1evn/AD) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first \$ n \$ values starting at \$ N=0 \$ whose value is considered to be \$ 0 \$. Explanation: \$ A253249(i) = \sum_{j|i} 1+A253249(j) \$ where \$ 0 \$ is considered to divide any integer.

```
ＦＮ
```

Loop \$ n \$ times.

```
⊞υ↨Ｅι∧¬∧κ﹪ικ⊕§υκ¹
```

Calculate \$ A253249(i) \$ using the above recurrence relation.

```
Ｉυ
```

Output the results.

22 bytes for a 1-indexed version:

```
ＦＮ⊞υ⊕↨Ｅι∧¬﹪⊕ι⊕κ⊕§υκ¹Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxDsIwEEN3viLjRSoSCImFqTBlaNVfCMmhRqSXKrlD/H1IN2CxZD/bbrbZJRtrfaSswNAqPMpyxwxaq0nKDNIpQy7jgsTo4WoLwmBXCJ3qycOYGIbkJSb4rgX9O3tq/Zf0bMjje/vfYKPHppfdlAMx3GxhkOZrPZ0Pdf@KHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first \$ n \$ values. Explanation: \$ A253249(i+1) = 1 + \sum_{j+1|i+1} 1+A253249(j+1) \$.

```
ＦＮ
```

Loop \$ n \$ times.

```
⊞υ⊕↨Ｅι∧¬﹪⊕ι⊕κ⊕§υκ¹
```

Calculate \$ A253249(i+1) \$ using the above recurrence relation.

```
Ｉυ
```

Output the results.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 31 bytes

```
f(n)=sumdiv(n,d,1+if(d<n,f(d)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboW-9M08jRti0tzUzLLNPJ0UnQMtTPTNFJs8nSApKamJkTVTZW0_CKNPAVbBUMdBWMDHYWCosy8EqCAkoKuHZAAGQJTCzMZAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <del>43</del> 28 bytes

Saved 15 bytes thanks to the comment of @alephalpha

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Yb899QO6Qo2lBb2UDfwTe/uMTBJbMsszi/qNhBOVbtf0hiUk5qdEBRZl5JdKaOgpKCrp2Cko5CWnRmbKyOQjVQyFBHwdigNvY/AA)

```mathematica
1+Tr[1+#0/@Most@Divisors@#]&
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcvBCoJAFIXhfU9xUIiiCZV2ldGiTTsXQovLJaZSvKAj6NBGfPbpBrU7/Ievs76pOuvlaUOoyd0Z@xw6GDlu4huaXvKWsR9GDZff1Hs2KHtvW1pl2OBaU4wjnFEas0HKayyRnPHHzIdFaR9tRcUgzpMYRNieEH2FsJJJU2awS2cO4QM)

```mathematica
f[n_] := f[n] = With[{divisors = Divisors[n]}, Total[(1 + If[# < n, f[#], 0]) & /@ divisors]];
Table[Print[i, " -> ", f[i]], {i, 1, 30}]
```

Comment: `1+Tr[1+#0/@Most@Divisors@#]&`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v1.4.5 [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>15</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
â à ®ä!v ×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.5&flags=LXg&code=4iDgIK7kIXYg1w&input=Mjg)

Thanks to @Shaggy for saving 5 bytes by using an older version of Japt ( improvements specified inside parens )

```
â       divisors( now sorted )
à       combinations( now without empty combination )
®       map by
ä       map each consecutive pair of a combination 
!v      divisible? ( now with argument swapped by prepending ! to function argument)
×       multiply reduce 

-x flag to output the sum
```

Comment: [10 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.5&flags=LXg&code=4iDgIK7kIXYg1w&input=Mjg) in v1.4.5

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 38 bytes

```haskell
f n=1+sum[1+f d|d<-[1..n-1],mod n d<1]
```

A simple port of @xnor's [python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265927)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN9XSFPJsDbWLS3OjDbXTFFJqUmx0ow319PJ0DWN1cvNTFPIUUmwMYyGq1-cmZubZFhRl5pWopCkYWUBEYWYBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>119</s> 118 bytes

```
L=[1...n]
D=L[mod(n,L)=0]
d=D.count
F=D[mod(floor(2k/2^{[1...d]}),2)=1]
f(n)=∑_{k=1}^{2^d-1}0^{mod(F[2...],F).total}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rwbvnz3yko)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/snsg5dz5ji)

Port of [Command Master's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265921/96039), so make sure to go upvote that answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

## APL (Dyalog Unicode), <s>51</s> <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
+/((∘.≤⍨⍳∘⍴)≡0=∘.|⍨)¨¯1↓{,⊃∘.,/⍵,¨⊂⊂⍬}(∪⊢∨⍳)
```

The index origin is set to 1 (⎕IO←1). The number to be analyzed is entered to the right of the code.

[Try it on TryAPL.org!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%2B%2F((%E2%88%98.%E2%89%A4%E2%8D%A8%E2%8D%B3%E2%88%98%E2%8D%B4)%E2%89%A10%3D%E2%88%98.%7C%E2%8D%A8)%C2%A8%C2%AF1%E2%86%93%7B%2C%E2%8A%83%E2%88%98.%2C%2F%E2%8D%B5%2C%C2%A8%E2%8A%82%E2%8A%82%E2%8D%AC%7D(%E2%88%AA%E2%8A%A2%E2%88%A8%E2%8D%B3)28&run)

With credit to [ngn's prior challenge answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154678/119285) for the short powerset code segment.